Error SSIS OLEDB Source/Target Editor, using Visual Studio 2022, Oracle DB
I am unable to preview data when using OLEDB Provider with oracle DB TNS name. oracle 12c 64 bit client and VS 2022(recently updated to version 17.8.6)
When I execute the task, it can fetch records, but preview data doesn't work, I didn't change any values for property "DefaultCodePage"
Oracle Connection Manager, 
Preview faile
Same component can fetch data when I execute it, I don't see error but I get warning without any error, 
warnings from previous execution
The OLE DB Command task doesn't show available parameters from update script so that I can map input values to update parameters.
when i refresh component after adding update script, 
Available parameters from update script are not showing up and unable to map parameters 
I have updated VS 2022 and reinstalled SSDT for VS 2022, then installed VS 2017 and SSDT to see if it works in other Visual Studio version but error is same in both visual studios. I am stuck and unable to make progress with OleDB component with an Oracle database.
Please let me know if I am missing anything.
There was an error displaying preview
